# Referencing to scripts using no specific links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've just found a site which has a lot of rows of tables in its html source. I was simply analizing that when I found a kind of button which whenever sb clicks on, toggles a javascript process but has no links to javascript functions.

```
<tr>
        <td class="text-center" style="'font-size:" 22px;&#39;="">3</td>
        <td>7889</td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs">23</td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs"></td>
        <td class="text-center hidden-xs"></td>
            <td class="text-center hidden-xs">1</td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="swb" id="5nDEYQFWTRk2RHtyMKUGdtVJZXg4DEzImRK8K/zUn1w="><i class="icon-list-alt icon-2x"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
```

now that last row is for that button.

When I was ckecking the code, I found no classes named `swb` or any ids with the name `5nDEYQFWTRk2RHtyMKUGdtVJZXg4DEzImRK8K/zUn1w=` in neither the html or css codes.
So can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Probably targeted with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Did you look at the javascript files? It's pretty straight forward to bind a click function onto an element via javascript  using an id or a class.